# How can i convert Syslog messages to columns

Tags: java, python, regex, syslog, cisco

I have just got my hands on a Cisco firewall . The firewall is accessed by syslog .
I am a new in using Syslog . From Syslog i can get outputs like this in a txt file .

```
08-03-2017  16:45:21    Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 %ASA-6-302013: Built outbound TCP connection 922 for outside:172.16.0.6/13000 (172.16.0.6/13000) to inside:192.168.1.10/50276 (210.4.73.234/50276)
08-03-2017  16:45:09    Local4.Info 192.168.1.1 %ASA-6-305012: Teardown dynamic TCP translation from inside:192.168.1.10/50274 to outside:210.4.73.234/50274 duration 0:00:30
```

I want the output to be similar like this .

```
 Built outbound , TCP , outside , 172.16.0.6/13000 , inside , 192.168.1.10/50276
Teardown dynamic, TCP , inside , 192.168.1.10/50274 , outside , 210.4.73.234/50274
```

Basically i want to remove the unnecessary words and keep the important ones .

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how can i convert the output file to the desired output format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java code for this is fairly trivial, I'll leave it for someone else to post it.

However, if you need this to be reusable/scalable, I strongly recommend you look at [logstash/elk](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash).  Using the logstash [syslog input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-syslog.html), you can process syslog files from multiple hosts and logstash will parse them and push them into almost any [columned format](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/output-plugins.html) you desire.

Note: No, I don't work for *elastic*, I'm just a satisfied user of this particular open source stack.